# Jekyll Data Declared in Post Yaml

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid

I have a file called 2015-12-04-galleries.yml in my _data folder. I can successfully parse it with the following.

```
{% for gall in site.data.2015-12-04-galleries %}
    <p> {{gall.name}} </p>
    <p> {{gall.address}} </p>
    <p> {{gall.url}} </p>
    <p> {{gall.url_show}} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

I am going to have a new file once a month. I would like to define a new layout, called event, to handle this. I would like to define the data source in the post yaml. Something like:

```
---
layout: event
data: 2015-12-04-galleries
---

{% for gall in post.data %}
    <p> {{gall.name}} </p>
    <p> {{gall.address}} </p>
    <p> {{gall.url}} </p>
    <p> {{gall.url_show}} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

I just can't figure out how to define the data source as a variable in the YAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get your datas :

```
---
layout: event
data: 2015-12-04-galleries
---

{% for gall in post.data[page.data] %}
    <p> {{gall.name}} </p>
    <p> {{gall.address}} </p>
    <p> {{gall.url}} </p>
    <p> {{gall.url_show}} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

But if you want to generate a page for each gallery, you try [Jekyll collections](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) that can automatically generate a page for each collection's item.

Comment: Thanks. I would have never figured out the [page.data] piece.

Answer (score 1):

As David Jacquel pointed out:

> But if you want to generate a page for each gallery, you try Jekyll collections that can automatically generate a page for each collection's item.

Jekyll collections might be a good solution for you. I just replied a question about it, with a step-by-step, so please check it out and tell me if it works for you: [Can I generate navigation from folder structure with Jekyll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34261890/can-i-generate-navigation-from-folder-structure-with-jekyll/34297038#34297038)

Comment: I am considering collections too. What I've been moving towards in an events layout. Now that I have this, I can just declare the data source. I can   add in a few words about the event, etc. which will be put into {content}. I do need to learn more about collections though.