# Dynamic folder layout in Jekyll

Tags: javascript, html, css, jekyll, liquid

Piggybacking from this question/answer [Can I generate navigation from folder structure with Jekyll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34261890/can-i-generate-navigation-from-folder-structure-with-jekyll)

I want to create a dynamic folder layout that will display the file structure of everything in the _docs folder. I need to do it this way because we are adding documentation and I want Jekyll to automatically generate navigation to the page.

Comment: Right now, it's not very clear what you're asking. What exactly is a "dynamic" folder layout? Can you please include some examples?

Comment: As an idea: why don't you try [Jekyll Hooks](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#hooks) prior to generation of _docs. Inside the hook you scan your directory for files, store results in a yaml file and use this file to generate the navigation?! However, this approach will not work if your pages are hosted on github.